# How does atom ide work

Tags: javascript, html, css, atom-editor

The background I have with Javascript and other Web Technologies is just creating web pages. So I am confused about how is Atom made using Javascript ? Is the editor using some interpretor ? But I never installed anything on my Ubuntu machine. Also nothing like that is mentioned on the Atom website. The question might be too noobish but I certainly am missing something. How does atom ide work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line of the [description of Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom):

> Atom is a hackable text editor for the 21st century, built on [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron), and based on everything we love about our favorite editors.

"Electron" is a [link](https://github.com/atom/electron), so let's click on it.

> The Electron framework lets you write cross-platform desktop applications using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It is based on Node.js and Chromium and is used in the Atom editor.

So, it's using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/).

Comment: Note: Even if you don't browse through the GitHub project, all this is also available directly from the official website.